# Is it possible to pass a value from a meta annotation?

Tags: kotlin, annotations

Let's say I have an annotation like this:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@EnumSource(value = MyEnum::class, mode = EnumSource.Mode.EXCLUDE)
annotation class TestEachValue
```

Is is possible to pass a value from my annotation class to one of the annotations on it? Something like:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@EnumSource(value = MyEnum::class, mode = EnumSource.Mode.EXCLUDE, names=excludes_from_below)
annotation class TestEachValue(val excludes: Array<String>)
```

I would be willing to wrap the value in an annotation if that helps. Or maybe Kotlin has some magic comparable to the `inline` keyword? Any advice on how this can be done nicely would be greatly appreciated.